# Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null. [React-Native IOS]

Tags: ios, react-native, upgrade

I just upgrade React-native from 0.62.2 to 0.63.4, and get this error. It is not clear from which library or module exactly it gave the error.Many people have encountered an error due to this **react-native-push-notification** library, but I could not find any error related to this **react-native-push-notification** library in any log. a library that I do not use in the project and is not installed

*[[And I noticed another strange thing. In react native 0.63 and above, the error is that the screen should have changed (So LogBox should be displayed) but as you can see this annoying red black screen is still displayed]]- it's not a big deal but i was just wondering why*

i updated everything in the upgrade helper
https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.62.2&to=0.63.4

```
System:
    OS: macOS 11.3.1
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
    Memory: 134.73 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.2.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: Not Found
    npm: 6.14.4 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.10.1 - /Users/ibrahimyolbir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 14.5, DriverKit 20.4, macOS 11.3, tvOS 14.5, watchOS 7.4
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.6 AI-192.7142.36.36.6241897
    Xcode: 12.5/12E262 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: javac 16 - /usr/bin/javac
    Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: ^16.13.1 => 16.14.0 
    react-native: ^0.63.4 => 0.63.4 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

```
Steps To Reproduce
Provide a detailed list of steps that reproduce the issue.
❯ pod deintegrate && pod cache clean --all
❯ pod install
❯ reinstall node_modules
❯ clean project
❯ reopen xcode
```

[image]

Comment: did you try with pod update?

Comment: yes i tried. I'm about to go crazy I've been trying to figure this out for 4 days and I don't know what to do anymore @FrancescoClementi

Comment: If could help you, the only two times that I needed to upgrade my react native version I created a new blank react native project and migrated all my code there

Comment: I solved my problem by undo the upgrade (I created a new branch) and I started the upgrade again by following the steps in the link.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/upgrading#react-native-projects